# Non-static method requires a target. Entity Framework 5 Code First

Tags: ef-code-first, .net-4.5, entity-framework-5

I am getting the error "Non-static method requires a target." when I run the following query:

```
var allPartners = DbContext.User
                           .Include(u => u.Businesses)
                           .Where(u => u.Businesses.Any(x => x.Id == currentBusinessId))
                           .ToList();
```

My entites are defines like this:

```
public class User : Entity
{
    public virtual List<Business> Businesses { get; set; }
}

public class Business : Entity
{
    public virtual List<User> Users { get; set; }
}

public class Entity
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
}
```

And my context is configured like this;

```
public class Context : DbContext, IDatabaseSession
{
    public DbSet<Business> Business { get; set; }
    public DbSet<User> User { get; set; }

    public Context()
        : base("DefaultConnection")
    {

    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove
            <System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Conventions.PluralizingTableNameConvention>();

        Database.SetInitializer(new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<Context, Configuration>());

        modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
            .HasMany(u => u.Businesses)
            .WithMany(b => b.Users);
    }
}
```

What have I done wrong?

Comment: Can you show the type of exception, possible inner exceptions and call stack?

Comment: It does not seem that the problem is in the code you showed.

Answer (score 125, accepted):

The problem boiled down to the query. My original question had this query:

```
var allPartners = DbContext.User
                       .Include(u => u.Businesses)
                       .Where(u => u.Businesses.Any(x => x.Id == currentBusinessId))
                       .ToList();
```

Which wasn't quite accurate, I had in fact removed the error in an attempt to ask my question succinctly. The query was actually:

```
var currentBusiness = GetBusiness();
var allPartners = DbContext.User
                       .Include(u => u.Businesses)
                       .Where(u => u.Businesses.Any(x => x.Id == currentBusiness.Id))
                       .ToList();
```

When the `GetBusiness` method returned `null` the error was thrown. Simply ensuring that I don't pass a `null` object into the expression made the error stop.

Comment: thank you, that's exactly what is happening to me. I would have chased my tail for hours on this.

Comment: Same here - random :) BUT very helpful answer - thank you!

Comment: I got the same problem. It helped me. Thanks