# Non-static method requires a target

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, entity-framework-5

I have a controller action that works fine on Firefox both locally and in production, and IE locally, but not IE in production.  Here is my controller action:

```
public ActionResult MNPurchase()
{
    CalculationViewModel calculationViewModel = (CalculationViewModel)TempData["calculationViewModel"];

    decimal OP = landTitleUnitOfWork.Sales.Find()
        .Where(x => x.Min >= calculationViewModel.SalesPrice)
        .FirstOrDefault()
        .OP;

    decimal MP = landTitleUnitOfWork.Sales.Find()
        .Where(x => x.Min >= calculationViewModel.MortgageAmount)
        .FirstOrDefault()
        .MP;

    calculationViewModel.LoanAmount = (OP + 100) - MP;
    calculationViewModel.LendersTitleInsurance = (calculationViewModel.LoanAmount + 850);

    return View(calculationViewModel);
}
```

Here is the stack trace I get in IE:

> Error.
>       An error occurred while processing your request.
>       System.Reflection.TargetException: Non-static method requires a target. at 
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.CheckConsistency(Object target) at 
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.InvokeArgumentsCheck(Object obj, BindingFlags 
>   invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture) at 
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder 
>   binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture) at 
>   System.Reflection.RuntimePropertyInfo.GetValue(Object obj, Object[] index) at 
>   System.Data.Objects.ELinq.QueryParameterExpression.TryGetFieldOrPropertyValue(MemberExpression me, Object instance, Object& memberValue) at 
>   System.Data.Objects.ELinq.QueryParameterExpression.TryEvaluatePath(Expression expression, ConstantExpression& constantExpression) at 
>   System.Data.Objects.ELinq.QueryParameterExpression.EvaluateParameter(Object[] arguments) 
>   at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ELinqQueryState.GetExecutionPlan(Nullable`1 forMergeOption) 
>   at System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.GetResults(Nullable`1 forMergeOption) at 
>   System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
>    at System.Linq.Enumerable.FirstOrDefault[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source) at 
>   System.Linq.Queryable.FirstOrDefault[TSource](IQueryable`1 source) at 
>   LandTitle.Controllers.HomeController.MNRefi() at lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase ,
>    Object[] ) at System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext 
>   controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters) at 
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext 
>   controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters) at 
>   Castle.Proxies.Invocations.ControllerActionInvoker_InvokeActionMethod.InvokeMethodOnTarget() at Castle.DynamicProxy.AbstractInvocation.Proceed() at 
>   Glimpse.Mvc3.Interceptor.InvokeActionMethodInterceptor.Intercept(IInvocation invocation) at Castle.DynamicProxy.AbstractInvocation.Proceed() at 
>   Castle.Proxies.AsyncControllerActionInvokerProxy.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary``2 parameters) at 
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass37.<>c__DisplayClass39.b__33() at 
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass4f.b__49() at 
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass37.b__36(IAsyncResult asyncResult) at 
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass25.<>c__DisplayClass2a.b__20() at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass25.b__22(IAsyncResult asyncResult)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Non-static method requires a target. Entity Framework 5 Code First](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13210867/non-static-method-requires-a-target-entity-framework-5-code-first)

Comment: Why do you think that a crash backend code has something to with the client application?

Answer (score 583, accepted):

I think this confusing exception occurs when you use a variable in a lambda which is a null-reference at run-time. In your case, I would check if your variable calculationViewModel is a null-reference.

Something like:

```
public ActionResult MNPurchase()
{
    CalculationViewModel calculationViewModel = (CalculationViewModel)TempData["calculationViewModel"];

    if (calculationViewModel != null)
    {
        decimal OP = landTitleUnitOfWork.Sales.Find()
            .Where(x => x.Min >= calculationViewModel.SalesPrice)
            .FirstOrDefault()
            .OP;

        decimal MP = landTitleUnitOfWork.Sales.Find()
            .Where(x => x.Min >= calculationViewModel.MortgageAmount)
            .FirstOrDefault()
            .MP;

        calculationViewModel.LoanAmount = (OP + 100) - MP;
        calculationViewModel.LendersTitleInsurance = (calculationViewModel.LoanAmount + 850);

        return View(calculationViewModel);
    }
    else
    {
        // Do something else...
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 This is definitely the result of an NRE in a `Where()` lambda expression. Great answer; saved me hours today.

Comment: Had the same issue with values not loading and being set from an inherited controllers constructor, then being passed into a linq query in the constructor of a child controller and throwing this mysterious error!

Comment: I think that the reason you get this error is that the Lambda is doing some reflection in the internals and it is trying to call a method/property on the object, but an object is not being passed in so it is trying to call the method/property like it is static but it eventually realizes that it is not static. This is why you don't get the plain old object reference not set to an instance of an object message.

Comment: Just reading the first sentence is enough to solve the problem

Answer (score 45):

Normally it happens when the target is null. So better check the invoke target first then do the linq query.

Comment: in my case it was a null reference exception in the where clause

Answer (score 15):

I've found this issue to be prevalent in Entity Framework when we instantiate an Entity manually rather than through DBContext which will resolve all the Navigation Properties. If there are Foreign Key references (Navigation Properties) between tables and you use those references in your lambda (e.g. ProductDetail.Products.ID) then that "Products" context remains null if you manually created the Entity.

Answer (score 8):

For anyone landing here encountering the error `Non-static method requires a target`  while running MS Test `[DynamicData] [DataTestMethod]` unit tests, the error is likely caused by not making your static data test scenario collection `static`, i.e. ensure you have:

```
public **static** IEnumerable<object[]> MyFakeData => 
        new[]
        {
            new object[] { "Foo" },
            new object[] { "Bar" }
        };

[DynamicData(nameof(MyFakeData))]
[DataTestMethod]
public void DoMyTests(string someData) {...}
```

It's super annoying to debug, as there's no useful stacktrace

Comment: Thank you!  This was spot on for me.

Answer (score 6):

All the answers are pointing to a Lambda expression with an NRE (Null Reference Exception).  I have found that it also occurs when using Linq to Entities.  I thought it would be helpful to point out that this exception is not limited to just an NRE inside a Lambda expression.

Answer (score 4):

(This is a simple example about the error)

This error occurred when the Linq query get the Data from DB context while the DB Context matching ID is null.
Suppose: We getting the Alumni Information from DB on the basis of Student record (reference table).

```cs
var getAlumniData = DBContext.Alumni.Where(a => a.AlumniID == loginHistory.AlumniID)
                      .Select(a => new Alumni
                       {
                          Enrollment = a.Student.Enrollment,
                          RegistrationNo = a.RegistrationNo,
                          Name = a.Name,
                       }).SingleOrDefault();
```

We get the matching ID from User Login History. If the user login history is null, then the loginHistory. AlumniID is null. So it error asked that the required target is needed.

Answer (score 3):

I face this error on testing WebAPI in Postman tool.

> After building the code, If we remove any line (*For Example: In my case when I remove one Commented line this error was occur...*) in debugging mode then
> the "**Non-static method requires a target**" error will occur.
>
> Again, I tried to send the same request. This time code working
> properly. And I get the response properly in Postman.

I hope it will use to someone...

Answer (score 1):

This could happen if you are using reflection to `GetProperty` of an object which is null.

Answer (score -1):

This occurred in my case because I was comparing to a `null` value. Something like this:

```
Guid? myGuid = GetMyGuid(someParameter); // This was returning null
var result = await _context.MyTable.Where(x => x.Id == myGuid).ToListAsync();
```

Comment: @GertArnold  Not sure why I have to explain this but anyway - My answer adds a very simple example. Other answers were not clear for me, they might not be clear for others.