# Getting non static method requires target error

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework

I am getting non static method requires a target error, and when I googled it I have seen posts to check null values and in my data I have all the values declared as not null and not sure why I am getting this error. Please help.

### MyCode:

I am getting total results by doing a call to Db

```
    var result = _retailerStatsRepository.GetAllRetailersForManufacturerCountryAndCategorySelectedDates(manufacturerRow.Id,
                                                                                        countryRow.Id,
                                                                                        categoryRow.Id,
                                                                                        cumLeads.StartDate,
                                                                                        cumLeads.EndDate);
```

### Note:

I am trying to use result for my further queries using Linq

```
   retailerWeeklyClickCount = result.Where(
                       i =>
                       i.Date >= localStart && i.Date <= localEnd && i.RetailerId == retailer.Id &&
                       i.ManufacturerId == manufacturerRow.Id
                       && i.CountryId == countryRow.Id && i.CategoryId == categoryRow.Id).Sum(i => i.WidgetClicks);
```

I am getting error so I tries below

### Edit

```
 var retailerWeeklyClicks = result.Where(
                        i =>
                        i.Date >= localStart && i.Date <= localEnd && i.RetailerId == retailer.Id &&
                        i.ManufacturerId == manufacturerRow.Id
                        && i.CountryId == countryRow.Id && i.CategoryId == categoryRow.Id);

 if(retailerWeeklyClicks!=null)
                    {
                        retailerWeeklyClickCount = retailerWeeklyClicks.Sum(i => i.WidgetClicks);
                    }
```

But still getting same error and checked inn my DB and I have no data only for few days between my startdate and end date for the category I have selected.

### StackTrace :

> at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.CheckConsistency(Object target)
>   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.InvokeArgumentsCheck(Object
>   obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters,
>   CultureInfo culture)    at
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags
>   invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
>   at System.Reflection.RuntimePropertyInfo.GetValue(Object obj,
>   BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] index, CultureInfo
>   culture)    at System.Reflection.RuntimePropertyInfo.GetValue(Object
>   obj, Object[] index)    at
>   System.Data.Objects.ELinq.QueryParameterExpression.TryGetFieldOrPropertyValue(MemberExpression
>   me, Object instance, Object& memberValue)    at
>   System.Data.Objects.ELinq.QueryParameterExpression.TryEvaluatePath(Expression
>   expression, ConstantExpression& constantExpression)    at
>   System.Data.Objects.ELinq.QueryParameterExpression.EvaluateParameter(Object[]
>   arguments)    at
>   System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ELinqQueryState.GetExecutionPlan(Nullable`1
>   forMergeOption)    at
>   System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.GetResults(Nullable`1
>   forMergeOption)    at
>   System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
>   at System.Linq.Enumerable.Single[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)    at
>   System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ObjectQueryProvider.<GetElementFunction>b__3[TResult](IEnumerable`1
>   sequence)    at
>   System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ObjectQueryProvider.ExecuteSingle[TResult](IEnumerable`1
>   query, Expression queryRoot)    at
>   System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ObjectQueryProvider.System.Linq.IQueryProvider.Execute[S](Expression
>   expression)    at System.Linq.Queryable.Sum[TSource](IQueryable`1
>   source, Expression`1 selector)    at
>   reporting.e_tale.co.uk.Controllers.ReportsController.CumLeadsParameters(CumLeadsReport
>   cumLeads) in
>   d:\e-tale-core-development\trunk\reporting.e-tale.co.uk\Controllers\ReportsController.cs:line
>   492    at lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] )    at
>   System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodDispatcher.Execute(ControllerBase
>   controller, Object[] parameters)    at
>   System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters)    at
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2
>   parameters)    at
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass15.<InvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__12()
>   at
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodFilter(IActionFilter
>   filter, ActionExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation)

As I am new to Linq , please help me if I am doing anything wrong.

Comment: Is this a *compiler* error? or an exception at runtime? Which part *specifically* reports the error? If this is an exception: what is the stacktrace?

Comment: When they're talking about `null` in this context, it means you are passing a null object into your query. It's not about your database columns being nullable. I see a few potential nulls: `manufacturerRow`, `countryRow`, `cumLeads`, `localStart` and `localEnd`.

Comment: For @Dennis http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13717355/non-static-method-requires-a-target   try and look here

Comment: Surely your first instinct should be to post the actual error instead of making us guess?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this and also check for null values

For example I am giving below for RetailerId:

```
object resultOfSum = result.Where(
                       i =>
                       i.Date >= localStart && i.Date <= localEnd && i.RetailerId !=null ? i.RetailerId== retailer.Id:i.RetailerId==null &&
                       i.ManufacturerId == manufacturerRow.Id
                       && i.CountryId == countryRow.Id && i.CategoryId == categoryRow.Id).Sum(i=>(int?)(i.WidgetClicks))??0;
                    if(resultOfSum!=null)
                    {
                        retailerWeeklyClickCount = (Convert.ToInt32(resultOfSum));
                    }
```