# Non static method requires a target C# Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

```
public InventorySales  getinvSales(int mgrId, int SalesId)
{
    Managerset res = null;


    InventorySales invSales = (from x in sbdb.tblSalesn.where(i => i.salesId == Sid)
                               join y in sbdb.tblProds on x.salesid equals y.salesid into resSales

     select new InventorySales()
                                      {
                                           ProductName = x.productname,
                                           Location = (xyz!= null) ? xyz.location:string.empty,
                                           Manager =  (res != null) ? res.Manager : string.empty // error line
                                      }).FirstOrDefault();

    return invSales
}
```

That's how my code looks,

```
Manager = (res != null) ? res.Manager : string.empty
```

is causing an error, there is no relation between the tblManager and tblSales table

Comment: Possible duplicate with: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13717355/non-static-method-requires-a-target/

Comment: What does the generated query look like?

Comment: i have used the null check, still it giving the erro (res != null) ? res.Manager : string.empty**

Comment: Do the null check outside of the query, populate the property afterwards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to move the `res != null` decision out of the query.

```
public InventorySales  getinvSales(int mgrId, int SalesId) {
    var res = from ins in sbdb.tblManager
          where(managerId == mgrID)
          select new Managerset() {
            Manager = ins.Manager
          }).firstOrDefault();

    InventorySales invSales = (from x in sbdb.tblSalesn.where(i=>i.salesId == Sid)
                                join y in sbdb.tblProds on x.salesid equals y.salesid into resSales
                                from xyz in result.DefaultIfEmpty()
                                select new InventorySales()
                                {
                                    ProductName = x.productname,
                                    Location = (xyz!= null) ? xyz.location:string.empty,
                                    Manager =  string.empty
                                }).FirstOrDefault();

    if (invSales != null && res != null) {
        invSales.Manager = res.Manager;
    }

    return invSales
}
```