# EF Non-static method requires a target

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I've serious problems with the following query.

```
context.CharacteristicMeasures
        .FirstOrDefault(cm => cm.Charge == null &&
                              cm.Characteristic != null &&
                              cm.Characteristic.Id == c.Id &&
                              cm.Line != null &&
                              cm.Line.Id == newLine.Id &&
                              cm.ShiftIndex != null &&
                              cm.ShiftIndex.Id == actShiftIndex.Id &&
                              (newAreaItem == null ||
                                  (cm.AreaItem != null &&
                                   cm.AreaItem.Id == newAreaItem.Id)));
```

I get a `TargetException: Non-static method requires a target`  when newAreaItem is null.
If newAreaItem is not null I get an `NotSupportedException: Unable to create a constant value of type 'PQS.Model.AreaItem'. Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context.`

Things I've already checked if they're null:
c, newLine, actShiftIndex all 3 variables are not null and the Id is accessible.

I dont get it... please help.

If u need more information.. dont hesitate to ask...

**UPDATE**

I could eliminate the `NotSupportedException`, but I still got the TargetException when my newAreaItemIsNull is true.. :/

```
bool newAreaItemIsNull = (newAreaItem == null);

var mc = context.CharacteristicMeasures
                .FirstOrDefault(cm => cm.Charge == null &&
                                      cm.Characteristic != null &&
                                      cm.Characteristic.Id == c.Id &&
                                      cm.Line != null &&
                                      cm.Line.Id == newLine.Id &&
                                      cm.ShiftIndex != null &&
                                      cm.ShiftIndex.Id == actShiftIndex.Id &&
                                      (newAreaItemIsNull ||
                                          (cm.AreaItem != null &&
                                           cm.AreaItem.Id == newAreaItem.Id)));
```

**UPDATE**

I finally did it. It seems that the query parse can't parse my `newAreaItem(IsNull)` because it's not in the DB model somehow !? 
I have to split my queries..

```
bool newAreaItemIsNull = (newAreaItem == null);

MeasureCharacteristic mc;

if (newAreaItemIsNull)
   mc = context.CharacteristicMeasures
               .FirstOrDefault(cm => cm.Charge == null &&
                                     cm.Characteristic != null &&
                                     cm.Characteristic.Id == c.Id &&
                                     cm.Line != null &&
                                     cm.Line.Id == newLine.Id &&
                                     cm.ShiftIndex != null &&
                                     cm.ShiftIndex.Id == actShiftIndex.Id);
else
   mc = context.CharacteristicMeasures
               .FirstOrDefault(cm => cm.Charge == null &&
                                     cm.Characteristic != null &&
                                     cm.Characteristic.Id == c.Id &&
                                     cm.Line != null &&
                                     cm.Line.Id == newLine.Id &&
                                     cm.ShiftIndex != null &&
                                     cm.ShiftIndex.Id == actShiftIndex.Id &&
                                     cm.AreaItem != null &&
                                     cm.AreaItem.Id == newAreaItem.Id);
```

Does someone know a better solution?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Non-static method requires a target. Entity Framework 5 Code First](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13210867/non-static-method-requires-a-target-entity-framework-5-code-first)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Try moving `newAreaItem == null` outside of the query

```
bool newAreaItemIsNull = (newAreaItem == null);
```

and replace `newAreaItem == null` with `newAreaItemIsNull` in query.

Query parser can only operate with the objects in the database, and newAreaItem is not one of them.

Comment: thanks. this helped to eliminate the NotSupportedException. Still when the newAreaitem is null i get a `TargetException: Non-static method requires a target` :/

Comment: i did fix it!!  your answer was the key. it seems that the query parser cant even operate with my boolean flag if it is true.. it seems that i have to write 2 times a nearly equal query. :/ you know a better solution ?

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem as you have when `newAreaItem == null` is true.

The problem comes from the fact that the item used in the LINQ cannot be null. Thus, when  `newAreaItem == null` is true it means that `newAreaItem` is null and this leads to the error being thrown.

All you can do in my opinion is, after checking `newAreaItem == null`, to set the newAreaItem to a new empty object of that type if `newAreaIteam` is null. The `newAreaItemIsNull` condition will still be in place, thus the

```
(cm.AreaItem != null && cm.AreaItem.Id == newAreaItem.Id)
```

in your code below will still not be evaluated if `newAreaItem` is null.

```
context.CharacteristicMeasures.
                                 FirstOrDefault(cm => cm.Charge == null &&
                                                      cm.Characteristic != null && cm.Characteristic.Id == c.Id &&
                                                      cm.Line != null && cm.Line.Id == newLine.Id &&
                                                      cm.ShiftIndex != null && cm.ShiftIndex.Id == actShiftIndex.Id &&
                                                      (newAreaItem == null ||
                                                       (cm.AreaItem != null && cm.AreaItem.Id == newAreaItem.Id)));
```