# Non-static method requires a target

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

Could you help me on this code

```
Profile ProfileDoctor = _context.Profiles.SingleOrDefault(p => p.ProfileId == id);
Users UserUser = _context.Users.SingleOrDefault(d => d.UserName == User.Identity.Name);
Profile UserProfile = _context.Profiles.Where(t => t.UserId == UserUser.UserId).SingleOrDefaul(); <--- Non-static method requires a target 
Meetings meeting = new Meetings
```

Comment: Since you require UserUser (badly named, call it userUser at the very least) to not be null, get it with Single, rather than SingleOrDefault.

Comment: Hey did you see my answer? did it worked?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Non-static method requires a target. Entity Framework 5 Code First](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13210867/non-static-method-requires-a-target-entity-framework-5-code-first)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are getting a null reference exception. It is called a non-static target exception since LINQ uses reflection. Check if that line does not return null. My guess would be that `UserUser` is null when trying to call the `UserUser.UserId` property.